# Laurent Series of a Polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm asked to write the Laurent series of $f(z) = z^2 - a^2. $ In any book that I read, it says that the expansion in Laurent series is done in a domain where $f(z)$ has singularities otherwise we can't expand in Laurent Series. Am I understanding, correctly, the definition of Laurent Series?

Can I expand $f(z) = z^2 - a^2$ in Laurent series?

Comment: You should have been given also a point around which the function is to be expanded, should not you?

Comment: You can do a Laurent series in a domain where $f(z)$ has no singularities, I think that just means it'll be equivalent to the Taylor series.

Comment: @user The professor didn't give me a point either...

Comment: @StephenDonovan so basically we expand our expression in Taylor series and that's it?

Comment: There is no general Laurent expansion of a function. It is a local property. If you are not given the point use $z=0$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laurent series around a removable singularity $z_0$ of $f$ is the power series of $f$ around $z_0$.